# how to convert httpresponse object to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, response, httpresponse

first of all i'm sorry because of my duplicated question but actually the other didn't work for me at all.

my problem is that I have 2 views which the first one is returning a Httpresponse to the 2nd, and what I want is to convert this Httpresponse to dictionary in the 2nd view and have access to it's elements.

here is the code :

1st view:

```
def base_tag_upload(request, tag):

error = False
upload_msg = "success"
user = request.user
response_data = {"error": error, "upload_msg": upload_msg, "file_id": None, "file_version": None}

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, tag=tag, user=user)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        uploaded_file = cd['file']
        collection_name = cd['new_name'] or uploaded_file.name.split('.')[0].strip()
        response_data.update(
            {"uf_name": uploaded_file.name, "uf_size": uploaded_file.size, "uf_colname": collection_name})
        set_primary = True  # first file in collection

        # Finding/Creating Related FileCollection
        collection = FileCollection.objects.create(name=collection_name)
        is_major = cd['version_type'] == 'mj'
        file_obj = collection.upload_file(uploaded_file, set_primary, Major_version=is_major)
        file_obj.author = user
        collection.tags.add(tag)
        collection.get_tag_permissions(tag, False)
        file_obj.get_collection_permissions(collection, False)
        set_user_ownership(collection, tag, user)
        set_user_ownership(file_obj, tag, user)

        collection.save()
        file_obj.collection = collection
        file_obj.save()
        response_data.update({'file_id':file_obj.id, 'file_version': file_obj.version})
        ActionLog.log(action=Action.objects.get(name="create"), target=file_obj,
                      user=user, request=request, details=None, extra_details=None)
        redirect_url = reverse('file_history', kwargs={'collection_id': collection.id})
        response_data.update({'redirect': redirect_url})
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps([response_data]))
```

and the 2nd one :

```
def tag_upload(request, tag_id):
try:
    tag = Tag.objects.get(id=tag_id)
except Tag.DoesNotExist:
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps([{'error': 'value_error', 'upload_msg': "no such folder"}]))
k = base_tag_upload(request, tag)
k.response.decode('utf-8')
print k
return base_tag_upload(request, tag)
```

but I got this error when I wanted to decode the Httpresponse as shown above :

```
AttributeError: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'response'
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `k.content.decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: but still i don't have the content :( what i get is :  "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"

Comment: change print k to print k.content to print the content

Answer (score 1):

> I have 2 views which the first one is returning a Httpresponse to the 2nd

Then you didn't structured your code properly - a view has no business calling another view not messing with the response.

If you need to share some common code between two views, then extract this code in a distinct function (that would in this case return a plain dict) and call this function from both your views.

Comment: Actually, this piece of code is a very tiny part of a huge project which I'm working on, so it's working and well-structured; i mean, the problem is not the structure for sure, but the lack of my knowledge to handle the Httpresponse and having access to it's content :( @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: Code structure has to evolve to accomodate new features, fixes and improvemennts. That's a very common task named "refactoring". If you write a new view that needs to execute the code from an existing view but update the context before returning the response, then the proper way to do this is **not** to mess with the `response` but to refactor the code by extracting the common part and make both views call the new function. That's how you **keep** a "working and well-structured" project.